# How to access test resources in Play 2.1?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to access a `.jpg` file that is inside my `src` folders with this line of code:

```
getClass().getResource("/teste.jpg")
```

That leads to `NullPointerException`.

I tried to put the file in the `app/` root directory. I also tried to put it in `test/` directory and also `test/resources` as well.

When I run the test from Eclipse it works fine, but it does not from command line using `play test`.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can achieve it by using

```
Play.application().getFile("file-relative-to-root")
```

It is dependent on the running application but for the unit test you can create your own application. Take a look into API docs.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/scala/index.html#play.api.Application

Answer (score 1):

Place the file under `public` or `app/assets` as described in [Anatomy of a Play application](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Anatomy). You can also have the test resources under `test/resources`.

```
[root]> help resourceDirectory
Default unmanaged resource directory, used for user-defined resources.

[root]> show test:resourceDirectory
[info] root/test:resourceDirectory
[info]  /Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/play-new-app/test/resources
```

With the resource file(s) in one of the directories, you can get at them as follows:

```
io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/teste.jpg"))
```